# Powershell Script To Get a Count of all Files in a Document Library

Tags: powershell

I am working on migrating data from sharedrives into Sharepoint and need to reconcile the figures at the end of the migration.
There are a few SharePoint sites and document libraries so doing this manually will take sometime. I have created a script to do this but on large document Libraries (100,000+ files) it takes a long time to run, has anyone got any advice on the script to speed it up or a better way to do it?

If I use the `Get-PnPList | select Title, ItemCount` it runs very quickly but this gives files and folders, and I just need the file count.

I have got the part of the script working to pick up specific document libraries and out put to a csv file this all works.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL= "https://staffordshire.sharepoint.com/sites/CFTTestTeamArea"
$ListName= "WIP Temporary"
  
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

#Get All Files from the document library - In batches of 500
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}
  
#Loop through all documents

$Counter=@()

ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
{
    $counter += $items.Count
}

write-host $counter.Count
```

Comment: `$ListItems.Count` doesn't give the number of items ?

Comment: Thanks @Christophe I have added the $Listitems.count as the following is this what you mean? #Set Variables
$SiteURL= "https://staffordshire.sharepoint.com/sites/CFTTestTeamArea"
$ListName= "WIP Temporary"
  
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

#Get All Files from the document library - In batches of 500
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 5000 | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"}


write-host $ListItems.Count